# do I need another .condarc for each environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I'm using anaconda and I needed to use `.condarc` to setup proxy settings.

Do I need to put another `.condarc` somewhere for an environment I created?  If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate `.condarc` for different environments. As I can tell you are aware, that file is used to store runtime configuration information for conda. In the [docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#the-conda-configuration-file-condarc), we see that it is used in (1) the user's home directory and, if you want, (2) in the root environment where it will override the user's `.condarc` configuration details.

The proxy server information that you have set in your home directory `.condarc` should be used in any environment you create.